# ARRAYFORMULA, QUERY, and IMPORTRANGE is only displaying results for a single row

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am wondering if there is an issue with my formula because its not filling the entire column like an array should.

Currently my formula is working perfectly with B2, but its not working for the entire range B2:B.

Here is my formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({
 {IMPORTRANGE("URL TO PRIVATE SHEET","$L2:$O")} 

},"select Col4 WHERE Col1 CONTAINS " & $A2:A))
```

**The IMPORTRANGE sheet looks like...**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GFnkuE3Dx-rTuvEV6wj1mCEq3P6cOxbzYco4aFVNw-I/edit?usp=sharing

```
|   L    |M|N|        O         |
| 000001 |*|*|JohnDoe@email.com |
| 000002 |*|*|JaneDoe@email.com |
| 000003 |*|*|BobDoe@email.com  |
```

**The ARRAYFORMULA is in B2**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JaWUWS3xKOwSX9y7uWUqEU5_Knp8nRgnhlVa1kRNlTo/edit?usp=sharing

```
|   A    |        B          |
| 000003 |  BobDoe@email.com | <- Contains the formula above and works.
| 000001 |        *          | <- No data: should say "JohnDoe@email.com"
| 000002 |        *          | <- No data: "JaneDoe@email.com"
```

Is this a limitation in Google Sheets? Thanks!

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheets?

Comment: Working on it now. Just migrating it to another account outside of an organization.

Comment: Updated question with URL to sheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cant have array in 2nd argument of query like that. try perhaps:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({{IMPORTRANGE("URL TO PRIVATE SHEET", "L2:O")}},
 "select Col4 
  where Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A2:A)&"'"))
```

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, QUERY({
 {IMPORTRANGE("1GFnkuE3Dx-rTuvEV6wj1mCEq3P6cOxbzYco4aFVNw-I", "L2:O")}},
 "select Col1,Col4 
  where Col1 is not null", 0), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This formula works in the sense of an array which is great, but does not take into account that the IDs may be in a different order than ascending. (refer to tab 2 "Formula Solution #1")

Comment: You are a wizard once again player0! Thanks for all your help!!!