# What's better practice? Multiple IMPORTRANGE formulas OR a single IMPORTRANGE + multiple local VLOOKUP formulas?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

What's better?

---

**Method #1** - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JaWUWS3xKOwSX9y7uWUqEU5_Knp8nRgnhlVa1kRNlTo/edit?usp=sharing

- Every tab (Team 1, Team 2....) has its own IMPORTRANGE formula in column B2

---

**Method #2** - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uND2IWlMese_ZDH37ITGf2LDwwLriheBbe9ozXAD8Yo/edit?usp=sharing

- Import Tab has its own IMPORTRANGE formula in column A2
- Every tab (Team 1, Team 2....) has its own local VLOOKIP formula in column B2

---

Data which is being IMPORTED: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GFnkuE3Dx-rTuvEV6wj1mCEq3P6cOxbzYco4aFVNw-I/edit?usp=sharing

---

I assume Method #2 would be better, but I just wanted to confirm.

Comment: @player0 - This is a reference based on the previous question you answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66285979/arrayformula-query-and-importrange-is-only-displaying-results-for-a-single-row/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2nd method is always better. importranges has its own limitations. you cant have many of them. also, they tend to slow down the overall performance because spreadsheets need to wait for data to be imported. if there is such option, its always good practice to import data with as few importranges as possible and the call for data locally